# On Windows 2003 how can I get the active power scheme using powercfg?

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-server-2003, powercfg

On Windows 7 I can use the parameter `getactivescheme` to get this information. How can I get it on Windows 2003?

On Windows 7 I can run the following code:

```
PS C:\Users\e> powercfg -getactivescheme
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
```

On Windows 2003, I get an error:

```
PS G:\> powercfg -getactivescheme
Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help
PS G:\>
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg-xp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quote from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324347/en-us)

> **/query, /q**
>    Use the following command to query each scheme to find out the settings: 
>   powercfg /query scheme
>    For example, if you run powercfg /query "always on", the settings for the Always On scheme appear. [...]
>
> If you do not specify a particular scheme, the default scheme settings appear. For example, if you run **powercfg /query, the settings of the current scheme appear**. The current scheme is listed in the Power Options tool in Control Panel.

In Windows 7 `Powercfg -query` displays the name and GUID of your active scheme in the first line.  Maybe the strategie for Windows 2003 would be similar. The following example shows you how to extract the scheme name with windows batch commands. Of course you can convert this example to powershell.

```
@echo off
powercfg -query > list.txt
set /p line=< list.txt  
for /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ("%line%") do set string=%%a
echo %string%
del list.txt
pause
```

#### How it works

- Pipe the output of `powercfg -query` to a temp text file
- Read back only the first line of the temp file
- strip out everything between ( and )
- display the scheme name with *echo*
- delete the temp file

Comment: Yes it does not work. It just shows some of the configurations of the active scheme, but no scheme name.

Comment: PS G:\> powercfg /query

Field Description          Value
-----------------          -----
Name                       Always On
Numerical ID               3
Turn off monitor (AC)      Not Supported
Turn off monitor (DC)      Not Supported
Turn off hard disks (AC)   Not Supported
Turn off hard disks (DC)   Not Supported
System standby (AC)        Not Supported
System standby (DC)        Not Supported
System hibernates (AC)     Not Supported
System hibernates (DC)     Not Supported
Processor Throttle (AC)    Not Supported
Processor Throttle (DC)    Not Supported
PS G:\>

Comment: In Windows 2003 it seems that it is the 4th line which contain the scheme name. In Windows 7 it is the first line. You have to customize the example.